# Open sets in locally compact spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Is every open set in a locally compact space an $F_\sigma$ set? Not assuming any separation axioms

Comment: Not in general. A $T_1$, non-Hausdorff counterexample is an infinite set with the cofinite topology. The Čech-Stone compactification of an uncountable discrete space is a compact Hausdorff counterexample. It *is* true in metric spaces.